# Make iMacros script automatically continue after getting website timeout error (-802 error)

Tags: javascript, imacros

I have an iMacros script (Firefox add-on) that runs during the night. I am also using a vpn. Occasionally I get a timeout error (-802 error) that pauses my iMacros script. I'm not sure if the vpn causes the timeout error, but that is a different issue. I have another script that logs the error to a google form. The form notifies me there was an error. Then I manually hit the continue button and the script goes on. Obviously this is a problem when I am asleep.

Is there a way to automatically have the script continue after a timeout error? If not, is there another way to simulate the pressing of the continue button in the browser?

Here is the code I use to notify me of an error:

```
var errorNotificationMacro;
errorNotificationMacro = "CODE:";
errorNotificationMacro += "URL GOTO=https://palemoon.stat.me/start \n"; // Removed r in start so the timeout error occurs
errorNotificationMacro += "TAG POS=1 TYPE=IMG ATTR=SRC:https://start.me/favicon/youtube.com \n";
errorNotificationMacro += "TAG POS=1 TYPE=SPAN ATTR=TXT:Trending \n";

macroName = "errorNotificationMacro";
returnCode = iimPlay(errorNotificationMacro);
if (returnCode < 0) {
    errorNotify(macroName, returnCode);
}

/* Utilties */

// Here is the function we call when there is an error
function errorNotify(macroName, errorCode) {
    iimDisplay("There was an error in the macro called " + macroName + " with this error code: " + errorCode);
    fillInTheErrorForm(macroName, errorCode);
}

function fillInTheErrorForm(macroName, errorCode) {

    formMacro = "CODE:";
    formMacro += "TAB OPEN \n";
    formMacro += "TAB T=2 \n";
    formMacro += "URL GOTO=[insert URL of Google form] \n";
    formMacro += "TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=ID:mG61Hd ATTR=NAME:entry.457171507 CONTENT={{MACRONAME}} \n";
    formMacro += "TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=ID:mG61Hd ATTR=NAME:entry.1604921625 CONTENT={{ERRORCODE}} \n";
    formMacro += "TAG POS=1 TYPE=CONTENT ATTR=TXT:Submit";

    iimSet("MACRONAME", macroName);
    iimSet("ERRORCODE", errorCode);
    macroName = "formMacro";
    returnCode = iimPlay(formMacro);
    if (returnCode < 0) {
        errorNotify(macroName, returnCode);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

why dont you use

```
SET !TIMEOUT_MACRO 15
```

15 seconds timeout for all the macros in the javascript

**Sample:**

In the below code timeout for the code is set to 60 seconds, thus giving more time for the macro to wait and not fail.

```
    formMacro = "CODE:";
    formMacro += "TAB OPEN \n";
    formMacro += "TAB T=2 \n";
    formMacro += "SET !TIMEOUT_MACRO 60 \n";
    formMacro += "URL GOTO=[insert URL of Google form] \n";
    formMacro += "TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=ID:mG61Hd ATTR=NAME:entry.457171507 CONTENT={{MACRONAME}} \n";
    formMacro += "TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=ID:mG61Hd ATTR=NAME:entry.1604921625 CONTENT={{ERRORCODE}} \n";
    formMacro += "TAG POS=1 TYPE=CONTENT ATTR=TXT:Submit";
```

Another options you can look into is

```
SET !ERRORIGNORE YES
```

So that the timeout error is ignored.

**References:**

1.[timeout](http://wiki.imacros.net/!TIMEOUT_MACRO)

2.[error ignore](http://wiki.imacros.net/!ERRORIGNORE)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tested SET !TIMEOUT_MACRO 15 and got a Macro Timeout error (-803). I will test it with a higher number. When I tried using SET !ERRORIGNORE YES the macro failed to work properly. This is because the macro that is triggering the one above is searching for links. When it does not find them it goes to the next step. If I use SET !ERRORIGNORE YES then the macro does not work at all.

Comment: So without set error ignore does the problem go away if you settimeout alone?